# Firebase query, rule for collectiongroup query getting in the way

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Just when I thought I had the hang of it, the query rules throws me a curve ball :(

I have this query rule:

```
// Needed for collection group (Member) query
// https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html
match /{rootPath=**}/Members/{member} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
}
```

It's pretty basic, only needs an authorized user.  collectiongroup query works perfectly as expected.

Now, I want to have another query just to get member documents:

```
Firebase.firestore.collection("Companies\\$companyID\\Members").get().await()
```

The query returns an error (PERMISSION_DENIED).

I also tried adding a rule just for members like this:

```
match /Companies/{companyID} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null &&
                isMember(database, companyID, request.auth.uid)
      
    match /Members/{member} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null 
    }
}
```

Still, the same error.

This is the document path:

[image: document path]

I looked at a few resources, but I didn't see anything to suggest a solution:

[Understanding Collection Group Queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards)

[Recursive wildcards](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html)

Comment: Could you try using instead of Firebase.firestore.collection("Companies\\$companyID\\Members").get().await() to add FieldPath?

Comment: Sorry,  but I don't understand the suggestion?  I don't see how your suggestion is different from the existing code posted above.

The query works, it's the security rules that apparently don't work.

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood the question. Is the issue still occuring?

Comment: Yes, the issue remains unresolved

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer, as it is too long for comment.

Have you tried the following example rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Companies/{companyID}/Members/{member} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

as mentioned earlier in the [documentation you shared](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data) based on structuring rules with hierarchical data?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this would not work...

The rule is for reading data only (so the 'write' option wouldn't be needed), but that said, this is a rule that must also cover collection group queries and the suggestion does not follow the requirements for those.   The query would work, yes but the collection group query would fail.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you have a look at the following [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules) where you can find some examples:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Companies/{companyID}/Members/{memberID} {
      // Only authenticated users can read
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Using the above security rules, any authenticated user can retrieve the *members* of any single *company*:

```
db.collection("Companies/{companyID}/Members").get()
```

---

Now , if you would like to have the same security rules applied to collection group queries, you must use *version 2*:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Authenticated users can query the posts collection group
    // Applies to collection queries, collection group queries, and
    // single document retrievals
    match /{path=**}/Members/{memberID} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Any authenticated user can retrieve the *members* of any single *company*:

But what if you want to show a certain user their members across all companies? You can use a collection group query to retrieve results from all members collections:

```
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    
  db.collectionGroup("members").where("author", "==", user.uid).get()
```

*Note: This query requires will require a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) for the members collection. If you haven't enabled this index, the query will return an error link you can follow to create the required index.*

Comment: As I mentioned above; the rule works correctly for collectionGroup query.  What I am having trouble with is performing a standard query for Company members documents.  I'd like to lock the query down to specific .

Answer (score -1):

You can try using "match /{path=**}/Members/{member}" instead of rootPath. I have not used the latter but the former worked for me in other projects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but 'rootPath' (or in your case 'path') is just the name of the placeholder, it's like a variable name and makes no difference.